# Iron Python script for cross Table taggle Rows Grand Total

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Can any one help me script for cross table rows Grand Total in a cross table.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turned up this code:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

#Script Parameter
myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()

#Show grand total for rows (not needed if creating toggle)
myVis.ShowRowGrandTotal = True

#How to toggle
if myVis.ShowRowGrandTotal == False:
    myVis.ShowRowGrandTotal = True
else:
    myVis.ShowRowGrandTotal = False
```

Reference: https://www.sf-ref.com/ironpython/visualizations/cross-table/appearance/

Attach that script to a button or some kind of action and you are good to go.

Comment: Hello Mark,  Thanks for your help. actually i would like to know toggle Rows Grand Total script in cross Table. Can you please help me.....

Comment: The `True` turns them on. Just wrap it in an `if else` case to turn them on if they are off and off if they are on.